# How kill all hidden (non-visible) buffers?

Tags: buffers, window, functions

I looked around to be sure, that none had this issue earlier.

Okay, sometimes I'm having too many buffers to manage. So I would like to kill all these buffers, except the buffers that are currently opened in my windows and elscreen.

I suspect there should be an existing function for that, [like in Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8450919/how-can-i-delete-all-hidden-buffers) but I couldn't found it inside Emacs and wiki pages.

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you are using ibuffer (this is the default buffer manager since Emacs 24.3 (I think?), then `C-x C-b` will bring up the buffer list, where you can mark the current buffer (usually the one on the top of the list) by pressing `m`, then revert the selection by pressing `t`, then kill all selected buffers by pressing `D` (these are the same keybindings you'd use in Dired).

Comment: What @wvxvw said, plus if you use `projectile` too, there is `ibuffer-projectile` package you can install. That will allow you to kill all buffers specific to a projectile project in one fell swoop (`m` on project name, `D`)

Comment: @wvxvw `ibuffer` is not the default. But you can always invoke `ibuffer-list-buffers` manually, no matter what you use.

Comment: @Malabarba ah, right, now I see that that's some modification that I've made and have forgotten, right then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't really think you want (ought) to do it, but this does it:

```el
(defun foo ()
  "Kill all buffers not currently shown in a window somewhere."
  (interactive)
  (dolist (buf  (buffer-list))
    (unless (get-buffer-window buf 'visible) (kill-buffer buf))))
```

Function `buffer-list` gives you all buffers. Function `get-buffer-window` checks whether a given buffer is shown in a window. Argument `visible` to `get-buffer-window` means check all windows on visible frames (ignore invisible and iconified frames).

Comment: Thanks for sharing. It works for a part, but not fully. I had a buffer open in the tab of elscreen, but it got deleted too. But I upvoted it anyway, even when it works only for windows.

Comment: Dunno what that means. If you are saying that `(get-buffer-window BUF 'visible)` returns `nil` for a buffer that you think is visible, then consider filing an Emacs bug report: `M-x report-emacs-bug`. I also don't know what you mean by "even when it works only for windows." But again, if you think that something doesn't work in all cases where you think it should, `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Comment: @Drew : obviously elscreen is something that has buffers "open/handled but not visible" in some way. If there's a (elscreen-manages-this-buffer buf) kind of function, the OP should add it to the conditions.

Comment: @YoungFrog: Dunno what is obvious. But if a buffer is visible in the ordinary sense, i.e., displayed in a visible window, then `get-buffer-window` should DTRT wrt that buffer. If it does not, that sounds like a bug, to me.

Comment: @Drew: From the initial question and the comments so far, it seemed obvious to me that these buffers are not visible in the ordinary sense.

Comment: Useful code in this answer -- was going to write this myself.  Not sure why it has a disclaimer; people use emacs in many different ways.  *IBuffer* becomes insanely flat and hard to read with dozens of buffers lying around.